# AWS Oracle RDS SE instance larger than m3.2xlarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

All,

I was wondering if we can pick anything larger than m3.2xlarge for Oracle SE1 AWS RDS in a pay-as-you-go license mode?

The m3.2x large allows only 8 vCPU's and 30GB RAM. Questions:

1. Does SE1 license allow to go with higher than 8 vCPU and > 30GB RAM
2. If yes, how do we go about using them in a pay-as-you go license
3. Is it possible to do so in a BYOL model if not in pay-as-you-go model?

We are looking at running Oracle SE1 on a 16 vCPU and 64+GB RAM instance, if possible. This is a legacy platform with a planned migration to MySQL in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> Does SE1 license allow to go with higher than 8 vCPU and > 30GB RAM

From page 11 of the [Oracle Software Investment Guide](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/software-investment-guide/index.html):

> Oracle Standard Edition One provides companies the total power of Oracle 
>   Database at an affordable entry price. Oracle Standard Edition One may 
>   only be licensed on servers that have a maximum capacity of 2 sockets.

And further down, on page 14:

> When licensing Oracle 
>   programs with Standard Edition One or Standard Edition in the product name, a 
>   processor is counted equivalent to an occupied socket

What this means, in a nutshell, is that SE1 can only be licensed on a server with two physical CPU chips in it.  The AWS instances that contain 8 vCPU's are likely 2 socket servers with 4 cores per socket, so it would fall within the license guidelines.  An instance like db.r3.4xlarge wouldn't qualify because it likely has 4 CPU sockets.

You could launch it on a server like a db.m2.4xlarge which would offer more RAM.  That would give you 68gb, which I believe is the maximum currently available for an RDS instance.

> If yes, how do we go about using them in a pay-as-you go license

AWS offers two license models, either "bring your own" or "license included".  If you use the license included model then Amazon will charge you a higher hourly rate for using the server than they would if you use your own license.  There are more details on these two license models in the [RDS documentation for Oracle](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/oracle/).  Amazon essentially uses a pay-as-you-go model by charging you for every hour your database is running.  All you do when you create your instances is select one of the two AWS license models.

> Is it possible to do so in a BYOL model if not in pay-as-you-go model?

Yes. Once again, you just choose the appropriate license model when starting up the instance.  You would just need to determine which is more cost effective for you based on how long you anticipate running this database within AWS, how much it would cost you to buy your own license from Oracle, and whether it would be cost effective to do that and pay the lower AWS rate instead of the higher rate for the "license-included" option.